# Where are chocolatey packages cached when installed with DSC

Tags: powershell, dsc, wmf

Working with the OneGet chocolatey provider, if I run the a command like the following...

```
Install-Package fooo
```

directly on a box the chocolatey package is cached in <%LocalAppData%>\Nuget\Cache. If I rerun the same command the package is read out of this cache.
However if I wrap up this command in a DSC resource and run it on a box I can not find where the package is cached.  It is definitely cached somewhere. anyone know where?  You would have thought it would be under the user that DSC was running as, although I am not sure what user it does run as and have also gone through all the user folders with no joy.

Comment: DSC runs as `SYSTEM`. Why does it matter where the packages are cached?

Comment: When developing and testing I do not wish to increment the version number with every tweak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DSC does indeed run as the local system account, thanks briantist.

It is cached here:  C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\NuGet

found with the help of the following link

https://serverfault.com/questions/9325/where-can-i-find-data-stored-by-a-windows-service-running-as-local-system-accou